# Joining two tables on a third in a single model Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables that I would like to treat as a single model class in Hibernate/Spring, however their only relationship can be established through a third table.  For example...

```
tableA {  
   id integer <PK>
   username varchar2(25 byte)
}
tableB {
   personID varchar2(15 byte) <PK>
   divisionID integer
   positionID integer
}
tableC {
   personID varchar2(10) <FK>
   username varchar2(25 byte)
}
```

While it would be very nice to simply add the personID as a column in tableA, circumstances do not permit.  I would, however, like to interact with these tables using one model in hibernate, such as the one below...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tableA")
public class myTable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;
   private String username;
   @Formula("(select distinct tableC.personID from tableC where upper(tableC.username) = upper(THIS_.username) and tableC.personID is not null)")
   String personID;
   @Formula("(select distinct tableB.divisionID from tableB where tableB.personID = THIS_.personID)")
   int divisionID;
   @Formula("(select distinct tableB.oositionID from tableB where tableB.personID = THIS_.personID)")
   int positionID;

   //getters, setters, etc...
}
```

I know that the way I have it written here is impossible, I'm just trying to convey the idea.  When I go to save or update the database later on, I would like for Hibernate to be able to update the appropriate tables from which each attribute came.

I have explored using @Transient, @SecondaryTables, and a few others but I haven't found a good way to make this work.  Is it possible to do this the way that I want to?  If so, what approach/annotations should I use?  If not, what alternative approach should I take?  I am relatively new to Hibernate and Spring, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a way to do this; I don't have an answer for you.

But your question suggests to me that you're not thinking properly about Hibernate.  It's an ORM tool - *Object*-Relational Mapping.  If you're still thinking just in terms of tables and SQL, loading values into primitives, then Hibernate isn't the right tool.

I'd suggest just using Spring `SimpleJdbcTemplate` rather than Hibernate if you don't have objects to map your data into.

Comment: In an attempt to make my question as straightforward, I may have oversimplified.  This is just one component of a much larger web application for which Hibernate has been very useful so far.

Comment: You don't have to use Hibernate for everything.  If you aren't mapping to model objects in your domain, I'd say Hibernate does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Using multiple tables in persistence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables)